# Can't log in to chat on stackexchange

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

I am having a new difficulty logging into chat.stackexchange.com. I have tried

- clearing my cookies
- clearing my cache
- clearing "everything"
- Firefox 3.6.something on Linux
- Firefox 7.0.1 on Windows
- Logging out of stackexchange, logging out of stackoverflow, logging out anywhere I can find
- Logging in with my Blogger openID
- Logging in with my Google account (didn't know I could do that)
- Logging in to StackOverflow, English.Stackexchange.com, stackexchange.com, superuser.com
- using the https://english.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login link, which gives me a 404 on chat for the url https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global-fallback.

When I log in with my OpenID the cross-site auto-login seems to work everywhere except Chat. When I use my Google account the cross-site login doesn't seem to work. I can get into the Stackoverflow chat with no problem but the stackexchange chat doesn't work for me. And I haven't changed anything in my browsers lately but this is a new problem for me.

I've gone to the chat help page and all tests pass.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: No error, when I visit the chat site I'm just not logged in, and when I click the log-in link I go to a page that says "Logging you in to the Stack Exchange chat…" but nothing happens.

Comment: I am having the same problem. The error I get is "Please log into any Stack Exchange site first", or similar. I am logged into SE chat fine here in the office, but can't get in from my home computer. MSO chat is fine for me, no problems...

Comment: @Abby MSO has a *completely different* login approach, for reasons that are quite boring.

Comment: Ah, I get it too when I tried logging in in a different session. It 404-ed trying to load http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/login/global

Comment: Ack; something does indeed have have gone "splut" with the login... looking

Comment: @Marc I thought I heard a little "splut" noise every time I attempted. Made an ear doctor appointment and everything.

Comment: @Abby can you confirm this is now working?

Comment: @Marc Seems to be working properly now - I just logged out and in successfully.

Comment: @Marc Still having trouble from my nonwork computer. Some troubleshooting left to be done on my end, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should now all be sorted; if not, please let me know.

Basically, a security library needed to be updated to the latest version, but nobody told me. So it wasn't. So it didn't believe the network's claim that you are you.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be better now. I wasn't auto-logged-in on the chat page but clicking the login link did the trick.

Comment: I keep telling people the problem is that they log out in the first place, but they don't listen.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Why didn't you tell him the security library needed to be updated? WHY?

Comment: I have pretty much the same problem. Sitewide login works everywhere except chat.SE. Tested with Opera, Chrome and FF on Win7. And if I choose the fallback I get lolcats. (myopenid as provider)

Comment: @CodeInChaos can you raise that with balpha? I'm conferencing for a few days...

Comment: @MarcGravell , Hi I have tried pretty much what the OP on this answer has. Using Safari, Firefox and Chrome. but still cannot login to chat. I have no problem with the stackoverflow chat. Any ideas. ta